# Partial differential equation solution $x u_x + y u_y = \frac{1}{\cos u}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a problem with a following task:

Let us consider an equation $x u_x + y u_y =  \frac{1}{\cos u}$. Find a solution which satisfies condition $u(s^2, \sin s) = 0$. You can
write down the solution in the implicit form $F(x,y,u)=0$. Find some domain of
$s$ values for which there exists a unique solution.

@edit:My progress so far:

System of characteristics:

$\begin{cases} x'(s,\tau) = x \\ y'(s, \tau) = y \\ u'(s,\tau)=\frac{1}{\cos(u)}\end{cases}$
(derivatives are with respect to $s$)

Initial conditions:

$\begin{cases} x(0,\tau)=\tau^2 \\ y(0, \tau) =\sin(\tau) \\ u(0, \tau) = 0 \end{cases}$

We calculate general solutions for those 3 equations, apply initial conditions, and we obtain:

$\begin{cases} x(s,\tau) = \tau^2 e^s \\ y(s, \tau)=\sin(\tau) e^s \\ u(s, \tau) = \arcsin(s) \end{cases}$

How can I now write down the solution in the form of $F(x,y,u)$?

I would be very grateful for any help ;-)

Best regards,

David.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Ok, I attached my work so far. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

What you have so far is correct. Your last system of equations yields $s = \sin u$, hence $x = \tau^2 e^{\sin u}$ and $y = \sin \tau e^{\sin u}$. So, 
$$|\tau| = \sqrt{xe^{-\sin u}}, \quad  \tau = \arcsin (y\,e^{-\sin u})$$
which leads to 
$$
\sqrt{xe^{-\sin u}} = |\arcsin (y\,e^{-\sin u})|
$$
There you have it, an implicit equation $F(x,y,u)=0$.

Of course, this computation is a minefield of non-invertible functions. But it seems that everything works as long as $|s|\le 1$, and there are issues after that, mostly due to the division in $1/\cos u$.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x$ , letting $x(0)=1$ , we have $x=e^t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=y_0e^t=y_0x$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{\cos u}$ , we have $\sin u=t+f(y_0)=\ln x+f\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$

Case $1$: $u(x=s^2,y=\sin s)=0$ :

$f\left(\dfrac{\sin s}{s^2}\right)=-\ln s^2$

$\therefore\sin u=\ln x+f\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$ , where $f(s)$ is the solution of $f\left(\dfrac{\sin s}{s^2}\right)=-\ln s^2$

Case $2$: $u(y=s^2,x=\sin s)=0$ :

$f\left(\dfrac{s^2}{\sin s}\right)=-\ln\sin s$

$\therefore\sin u=\ln x+f\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$ , where $f(s)$ is the solution of $f\left(\dfrac{s^2}{\sin s}\right)=-\ln\sin s$